# trying to use an Oauth2 access token using httpwebrequest

Tags: oauth-2.0

First of all let me tell you that the code I am writing is not to be used for any socials or app but for a private REST API.

I was able to get the access token, but now when I am using it I get a 401 error.
The documentation I have been given uses Python and a third party dll called Requests (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest ). Both documentation and library are not of any use for me as I am developing in DOT NET.

According to the code example: *# This request uses a custom authentication method which adds the access token to the request according to the OAuth2 specification.*

so I am using this line:

```
request.Headers.Add("x-Authorization", "Access_Token access_token=" + Tok);
```

whereas the python line of code is this

```
response = requests.get(list_transfers_endpoint, auth=AccessTokenAuth(access_token), verify=False, params=payload)
```

where list_transfers_endpoint is the URL
payload is just another parameter that I can add it to the request 
verify false is used because test servers do not have an approved SSL certificate. I am overcoming to the SSL problem by using this line

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

which worked for getting the token.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I have found the answer, not sure if this is the right way to notify it in here.. however by using  
'request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer " + Tok;'

instead of:
request.Headers.Add("x-Authorization", "Access_Token access_token=" + Tok);

it worked!